# How can I extract the core of a Wordpress Theme and transfer / recode it to be used in Modx?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, modx, modx-revolution, modx-templates

I have bought WP Themes to look at their code so that I can transfer them to Modx, are there specific folders I should look out for? If it helps one of the Wordpress Themes (Roots), uses the HTML5 Boiler Point and Twitter's Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Viewing Wordpress page source will do very little for you. You're going to get rendered php outputted for features and functions that have no relation to MODx.

Read MOSx's own docs on the process: **MODX College: Porting WordPress Themes**
http://modx.com/learn/modx-college/porting-wordpress-themes/

Answer (score -1):

To do that follow the steps below:

1. Install your theme in wordpress.
2. View the wordpress with the new theme installed.
3. View the source of the page (Ctrl + u).
4. Copy the source.
5. Create new template in MODx.
6. Paste the copied source code to the new template you've just created.
7. Assign the template to a page (ie. home) and save.
8. View the page (click the 'View' button).

You will see, there will be all css, js, images and other files missing. Simply link all of these files in the newly created template. It's best to put them in the following directories on the server:

- /assets/css/
- /assets/js/
- /assets/images/

After all files will be linked, select and cut the content from the template and paste it to the 'content' area of one of the resources (ie home) and click save.
In the template instead of the content you've just cut out, put
`[[*content]]`.

That's basics. You can continue with other adjustments. MODx is very comfortable once you'll get a grip on it.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is similar to:

View HTML output from the  WordPress theme and weaving the HTML/CSS/JS into MODX as if WordPress never had anything to do with the design. WP has a theme structure whereas MODX has no theme or template guidelines or structure—you have 100% control over all output. You may be able to use the PHP files in the theme as a reference for areas to create TVs, chunks etc. 

Source: http://www.quora.com/MODX-CMS/How-can-I-extract-the-core-of-a-Wordpress-Theme-and-transfer-recode-it-to-be-used-in-Modx